# Python - loop still going

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to write a program similar to a blind auction, but I am having issues with the while loop. I don't understand why the loop is not ending. I used Thonny and even after the player enters 'no', it seems like the loop is breaking since it prints **what is outside the loop** and then goes to the bid function inside the while loop, with the player value set to 'yes'. I don't understand why this is happening. I have just started learning Python, so I would appreciate any help in explaining why this is occurring. Thank you!

```
def bid(player_name,player_bid):
    player_name = input("What's your name?\n")
    player_bid = input("What's your bid? PLN")
    bid_list[player_name] = player_bid

    while True:
        player = input("Are they any other users? Insert yes or no?")
        if player ==  "no":
           player = "no"
           break
    bid(player_name,player_bid)
  
  max_value = max(bid_list.values())
  print(f"{player_name} has the highest bid - {max_value} ")

  print("Thank you for playing")

player_name = ""
player_bid = 0
bid_list = {}

bid(player_name,player_bid)
```

I did try to change the code many times and used ChatGPT but still I don't understand why my code is not working.
After I switched some part in while loop the code is working but I want to understand why my code is not working and why the loop is not ending.

Comment: Your indentation is messed up. If `max_value` is inside the function, it needs more indentation (the same as the previous lines). If it's not inside, it should have no indentation.

Comment: Your function calls itself unconditionally. So you have infinite recursion.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to correct it but you did that for me! Thank's! I see, I did delete that bid function inside while loop and added just inputs and the code was working but I still didn't understand why calling a function was messing up the program.

Comment: `if player == 'no': player = 'no'`. It already equals "no" assigning it isn't going to make it equal "no" even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use recursion as a substitute for looping. Put your `while` loop around all the code that asks for player names and bids. Your recursion is outside the `while` loop, so it occurs every time and you never get out of the loop.

There's also no need for `player_name` and `player_bid` to be function parameters, since the function assigns those variables itself from user input. You could instead pass in `bid_list` as a parameter.

Your `max()` call gets the maximum bid, but not the player that made that bid.  Get the maximum of `bid_list.items()` which returns both the keys and values.

```
def bid(bid_list):
    while True:
        player_name = input("What's your name?\n")
        player_bid = input("What's your bid? PLN")
        bid_list[player_name] = player_bid

        player = input("Are they any other users? Insert yes or no?")
        if player ==  "no":
            break

    max_player, max_value = max(bid_list.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(f"{max_player} has the highest bid - {max_value} ")

    print("Thank you for playing")

bid_list = {}
bid(bid_list)
```

Comment: WOW, your code looks more clean and easy to understand. Thank you for the explanation I think that now I understand my errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling

```
bid(player_name,player_bid)
```

inside of the bid function and creating an endless loop that way.

Comment: Thank you, so calling that bid function inside a while loop is messing up the code, I did change that and delete it and added inputs there and the code is working. Not sure if there is a way that adding that bid function inside would not break the code...